# How to measure the different or similar of 3 set of data after using Kmean clustering

Tags: mathematical-statistics, k-means

Suppose I have a group data and I apply K-mean algorithm to clustering it to 3 group. My question is when we have 3 group separate, how do I know the distance of 3 group is close or far each other with the flexible threshold. (Ex1: 3 means of 3 groups is 7;7.5; 7.9 is close but in case 1;3;10 we can say 2 group close and 1 far. Ex2: 3 means 1;5;9 we can say 3 group far each other). I don't want to put the fix value distance threshold because of unknown the range of value Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your problem is not the threshold specification, but that you want the distance between the three points to be measured in "relative" terms. If you use Canberra distance, you can get what you want, but you still have to specify the threshold. Otherwise, it's not clear how the algorithm can distinguish between (7;7.5; 7.9) and (1;5;9).